# Can we install a VM inside a VM

Tags: openedx, vmware-tools

I have a VM machine (Ubuntu 64 bit) on Vmware environment and I want to install Openedx on it. I have also installed a VirtualBox using vagrant (as part of the requirement of Openedx). However when we want to run the Vagrant using vagrant up command, the VirtualBox VM (9b8279a4-210c-4aae-886e-4927e4ea8a5f) which is inside my host VM is not booting up?...

I have enabled VT-x in my host VM environment (Ubuntu 64 bit).

Error encountered is:

```
Command: ["startvm", "9b8279a4-210c-4aae-886e-4927e4ea8a5f", "--type", "headless"]

Stderr: VBoxManage: error: VT-x is not available (VERR_VMX_NO_VMX)
VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component ConsoleWrap, interface IConsole
```

[0;31mThere was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Answer (score 0):

It's saying that VT-x is not available i.e. Virtualization is not available on your machine .. genrally you would go to the BIOS settings and make changes there, but since it's a VM for you  you will have to enable VT-X on the VM.

You need to go to edit settings of a VM,  expand the "CPU" section and select "Hardware Virtualization" box to enable VHV.
 For a detailed explanation you can check out this article.
https://www.virtuallyghetto.com/2012/08/how-to-enable-nested-esxi-other.html

As for you other question

> Can we have a VM on top of a VM ?

Yes you can, but ensure you have the latest/best hardware  as which supports Virtualization and can handle multiple VM for a more detailed explanation check out this article
https://serverfault.com/questions/46960/is-it-possible-to-setup-a-virtual-machine-inside-another-virtual-machine

Comment: Thanks Rohit for the reply, however when I navigate to my VM Edit Setting --> Options --> CPU/MMU Virtualization i found 4 options.  (1) Automatic (2) Use software for instruction set and MMU Virtualization (3) Use Intel VT-X/AMD-V for instruction set virtualization and software for MMU virtualization (4) Use Intel VT-x/AMD-V for instruction set virtualization and Intel EPT/AMD RVI for MMU virtualization.